# Align two charts (achartengine) side-by-side

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm trying to show two charts in my activity. One LineChart and one ScatterChart. If the smartphone / tablet is in portrait, the charts shall be among each other. If the device is in landscape, the shall be side-by-side, each with 50 % of space.

I'm stucked here. Should I use a LinearLayout for each chart or one for both? How can I align them the right way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put both your linear layouts inside a `LinearLayout`, with both of them having `width="0dp"`, and `weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Though I had to add android:orientation="horizontal" since eclipse threw some errors.